# Not giving proper message, when my .ini file's strvalue is null or empty

Tags: c#, if-statement

i am reading a strvalue from .ini file. Its reading and every thing is working fine. But i wanted to show something like when the keyname and strvale is not there i want to show a message box like "contact admin".

So when i coded on the `form_load` even.. each time the form is loading with the message box. lol. i dont khow to correct it. Please help me out.

My code snippet

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(ini.ReadValue("Action", "User")))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Contact Admin");
            Environment.Exit(0); 
        }
       else
        { 
        //do something
        }
   }
```

**Code in my .ini file**

```
  [Action] 
  User=Company\Group
```

I am looking for something like if the .ini `[Action] filed is empty`, means like below!!!

```
[Action]
User=
```

So i need to show an message box on form load and i want to exit.

I have made a seperate class to read and write .ini file.
Code snippet for .ini file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MovedFiles
{
class INIFile
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern int WritePrivateProfileString(string ApplicationName, string KeyName, string StrValue, string FileName);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string ApplicationName, string KeyName, string DefaultValue, StringBuilder ReturnString, int nSize, string FileName);

    private string fileName = string.Empty;
    public INIFile(string _fileName)
    {
        fileName = _fileName;
    }
    private string DefaultSection = "SECTION1";
    public INIFile(string _fileName, string _defaultSection)
    {
        fileName = _fileName;
        DefaultSection = _defaultSection;
    }

    public void WriteValue(string SectionName, string KeyName, string KeyValue)
    {
        WritePrivateProfileString(SectionName, KeyName, KeyValue, fileName);
    }

    public string ReadValue(string SectionName, string KeyName)
    {
        StringBuilder szStr = new StringBuilder(255);
        GetPrivateProfileString(SectionName, KeyName, "", szStr, 255, fileName);
        return szStr.ToString().Trim();
    }

    public void WriteValue(string KeyName, string KeyValue)
    {
        WriteValue(DefaultSection, KeyName, KeyValue);
    }
    public string ReadValue(string KeyName)
    {
        return ReadValue(DefaultSection, KeyName);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you are reading the wrong code

Comment: No.. Who need to do like that!!! I need to show the message box!! if the .ini file's Action filed.. is empty.. Just to show a message "contact admin" if filed is emplty:p

Comment: Don't use an ini file.  Use an xml file and serialize/deserialize the entire setting in 3 lines or so..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check like this. you are checking File is exist or not instead of value is null or not.

```
string strVal = ini.ReadValue("Action", "User");
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(strVal))  //This will return true if the value is null or blank.
{
    MessageBox.Show("Contact Admin."); //So the message will display only when value is not assinged.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One issue is that you are using `System.IO.File.Exists()` on something that is not a file path. I don't know what library you are using to read the ini file, I imagine it is just wrapping the Win32 calls. You may be looking for something like:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ini.ReadValue("Action", "User")))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Contact Admin.");
}
```

This assumes you have specified the file and checked that it exists when creating the `ini` variable.

Comment: @BobbyShaftoe. I think `File.Exists` should return `false` for both `null` or `empty`.

Comment: Ohhh sorry its not working.. its same for both case.. i gave the path there.. still its showing contact admin

Comment: @StacyKebler, post `ini.ReadValue code` in your question.

Comment: @StacyKebler. Answer is correct. You can have values in `string sUserVal = ini.ReadValue("Action", "User");` then check it with `string.IsNullOrEmpty`

Comment: @HassanNisar Sorry i dint get that

Comment: Still its the same.. i gave likt this `string sUserVal = ini.ReadValue("Action", "User");
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sUserVal))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Contact Admin.");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }`

Comment: @HassanNisar, I agree that File.Exists returns false in this case but really it will always return false given that the result of ReadValue, as I can tell, in this case,  will never be a valid file path but rather some kind of user designation.

Comment: @BobbyShaftoe. I got your point. I was thinking that OP is supposed to input path as a value to `User` key. 
@StacyKebler I think you have to rephrase what you are trying to achieve.